# I would like all my select classes including those that might be added later to use select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code:

```
$(".select2")
    .select2();
```

All the select2 classes have the the .select2() applied to them.

However I have code that adds html (including selects to my web page. Do I need to run the same code above after the new content is added?

Comment: What does select2 actually do?

Comment: It changes the selects to styled selects. http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-latest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you would need to rerun this method to style the new `select` elements.

Depending upon how you are adding the `select` elements it is probably worth adding in this method into the callback.

As an example using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "garfieldIsTheBestCatEver.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        //Guess at data being your select here
        var $this = $(data); //Make the data a jQuery object;
        $this.select2(); //Run your method
    }
});
```